# the dropdown menu watermark is different from other fields

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

i have a request registration form.In that there are first name ,last name,career etc .The water mark of career which is a drop down menu is different from other fields.it is a bit darker.I want the watermark of career level should be same as fistname and lastname watermarks.here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JxfLw/ ...here is my html and css code

```
 <span class="sticky-placeholder-wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block;"><input type="text" id="txtFirst" title="First Name" class="newpost1" maxlength="25" tabindex="11" data-sticky-placeholder="*First Name"><label id="firstname" class="sticky-placeholder-label" for="txtFirst" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: text; font-family: futuraltbook; font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px; left: 6px; line-height: normal; opacity: 0.5; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 3px; position: absolute; text-transform: none; top: 0px;">*First Name</label></span>
        <span class="sticky-placeholder-wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block;"><input type="text" id="txtLast" title="Last Name" class="newpost1" maxlength="25" tabindex="12" data-sticky-placeholder="*Last Name"><label id="firstname" class="sticky-placeholder-label" for="txtLast" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: text; font-family: futuraltbook; font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px; left: 6px; line-height: normal; opacity: 0.5; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 3px; position: absolute; text-transform: none; top: 0px;">*Last Name</label></span>
            <select id="selMemberType" size="0" class="empty side space  selectPlaceholder" tabindex="13">
                <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">*Career Level</option>
<option value="1">Student</option>
            <option value="2">Entry Level</option>
            <option value="3">Experienced</option>
            <option value="4">Manager</option>
            <option value="5">Executive</option>
            <option value="6">Senior Executive</option>
            <option value="7">Senior Management Executive</option>
            <option value="8">Celebrity</option>
        </select>
#txtFirst, #txtLast {
border-top: 1px solid #666!important;
border-right: 1px solid #666;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-left: 1px solid #666;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgba(30,31,32,.58);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #555;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #000;
float: none;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#selMemberType {
height: 32px!important;
border-top: 1px solid #666;
border-right: 1px solid #666;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-left: 1px solid #666;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgba(30,31,32,.58);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #555;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #000;
font: normal 18px futuraltbook!important;
clear: both;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 0;
width: 545px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you added js to your tags, i believe you accept an answer js included. But first add this styles to your css

```
.selectPlaceholder {
  color : #444;    
}

select option:not([disabled]) {
  color : #000;    
}
```

And the js code

```
document.getElementById("selMemberType").onchange = function(){
  this.className = this.className.replace("selectPlaceholder","");
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JxfLw/1/)**

Comment: though its working on fiddle ,its not working on actual code .I couldn't find any difference .

Answer (score 0):

Please change some css properties in #selMemberType as given below

```
height: 20px!important;
font: normal 14px futuraltbook!important;
width: 240px;
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question the watermark of career level should be same as fistname and lastname watermarks